# psql --version - Library not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

so I'm running this railscast to setup postgres with my rails app:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

the brew install worked fine - postgres was installed on my system successfully.

now I'm running

```
psql --version
```

to check the latest version installed. Instead of the version that should be displayed now I'm getting

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

googled that error but could not find help and now I'm really stuck. no idea what to do

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed by running this

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```